How can one export an animated GIF for SE posting?
Following this decision to limit animated GIF sizes I don't agree with, I've been having a hard time knowing how to ask questions that require visual documentation on SE sites like Graphic Design, Blender, etc.
I understand that there is a "50 megapixels" limit, which computes the total number of pixels in the animation, but what type of software can create or export an animated GIF based on total pixels?
Is there a browser-based tool that could easily shrink or split an animated GIF to meet SE's new requirements?



How can one export an animated GIF for SE posting?

Convert it to APNG (has a size limit of 2 MiB but no pixel limit).

Could you be more descriptive in your answer on how to create a APNG file that complies with SE? I work in graphic design, use professional editing tools (adobe CC), and have never heard of "APNG". Or maybe a screen recording tool that creates an APNG file. When SE made the switch it would have been a great idea to provide its users with some kind of guide on how to keep using the site.

@MicroMachine https://ezgif.com/gif-to-apng then compress down to 2 MiB via crop/resize/etc.
